# Синхронное изменение данных при множественных запросах

Tags: node.js, база-данных, mongo

Работаю над созданием api, столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

У меня есть роут, по запросу к которому в БД меняется некоторая data.
Вот так схематически выглядит функция:

1. Получение данных из бд
2. Некоторая бизнес логика занимающая время
3. Изменение и сохранение данных в бд.

Проблема в том, что выполнение запросов к бд и бизнес логики занимает время, и если, до полного их завершения придёт ещё один запрос, то изменения внесённые при первом запросе ещё не будут применены, и как следствие, второй запрос получит из бд старые (не обновленные) данные.
Основываясь на них будет получен не верный результат, и сохранен в бд.

Какие есть способы бороться с этим, возможно какие-нибудь паттерны или стратегии? Я уверен что подобная проблема решалась уже не единожды, но не знаю как правильно найти информацию на этот счёт.
Пожалуйста подскажите в каком направлении искать, что почитать на этот счёт? Какие есть правильные варианты решения?

Comment: Если выборка данных это одна строка по ID то еще можно придумать костыли(допустим очередь организовать в приложении), если выборка - набор строк, то ближе к никак. В реляционных БД есть возможность заселектить записи с `for update` что вешает блокировку на записи, однако в этом случае, надо либо переносить логику на БД, либо не рвать соединение после выборки и выполнять фиксацию изменений в текущей сессии.

Comment: Mongoose используете? Там вроде что-то встроенное есть для optimistic concurrency.

Comment: А так классически используется дополнительное поле version, которое инкрементируется при каждой записи/изменении. При сохранении своих данных проверяете это поле - если оно отличается от текущего, значит кто-то другой уже изменил этот документ. Считываете его заново и повторяете процесс.